# BigTiff to JPEG 2000 using Python

Tags: python, image, tiff, jpeg2000

I am trying to convert large (+50 GB) BigTiff images into JPEG 2000 format for post analysis using Python. I have succeeded on converting the large BigTiff files into JPEG using `libvips`; however, `libvips` does not have direct support for JPEG 2000 - what a bummer

I have been able to write JPEG 2000 images using `glymur` but the problem with `glymur` is that writing JPEG 2000 images is currently limited to images that can fit in memory. Since my workstation haves only 8 GB of RAM it would be impossible to convert a +50 GB file into JPEG 2000.

If anyone could point me into the right direction on converting a BigTiff into JPEG 2000 efficiently using a RAM limited work station, I would like to hear about it.

Cheers,

-Frank

Comment: Have you tried [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) yet?

Comment: Try tifffile to [read BigTIFF tile by tile](https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile/blob/025b5e0e0046a4dd0990852fe423c262f5338d72/tifffile/tifffile.py#L558-L570) and Glymur/OpenJPEG to [write JPEG 2000 tile by tile](https://github.com/quintusdias/glymur/blob/7c02566ed2d72b039294b97fe5fd8f969fb5ec87/tests/test_openjp2.py#L179-L251).